# Fatal error: Array index out of range (Parse/Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I tried running it from my own array within the file but now when i try to get it from parse it's giving me this error... 
Even when i put a number in the square brackets it doesn't work.

```
@IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var answerTF: UITextField!
var question : String! = ""
var answer : String! = ""
var objectIDArray = [String]()
var randomID = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let objectIdQuery : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "QuestionsAndAnswers")
    objectIdQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects : [PFObject]? , error : NSError?) -> Void in

        var objectID = objects! as [PFObject]
        for i in 0..<objectID.count {
            self.objectIDArray.append(objectID[i].objectId!)
            self.callData()
        }
    }
    callData()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func getRandomObjectID() {
    randomID = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(objectIDArray.count)))
}

func callData() {
    getRandomObjectID()
    let query : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "QuestionsAndAnswers")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(objectIDArray[randomID]) "<- The error is pointing here" {
        (object : PFObject? , error : NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            self.question = object!["Question"] as! String!
            self.answer = object!["Answer"] as! String!
            self.questionLabel.text = self.question

        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem happen here:

```
randomID = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(objectIDArray.count)))
```

expample array have 3 number when random is 3.

you access: objectIDArray(3) it out of range because range is [0..2].

So you change it to:

```
randomID = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(objectIDArray.count - 1)))
```

Comment: It worked when I set the array by copying the objectIds from parse and putting in the file and and everything worked perfectly. but when I tried getting the objectIds from the server so I don't have to update the app every time it started giving me this error. Plus when I put minus one it gave me an error :  (lldb)

Answer (score 0):

I got it, I used the callData() twice, once in the for loop and the other right outside of it. Silly mistake...

Answer (score 0):

i guess the possible problem could be this line

```
var objectIDArray = [String]()
```

you are not allowed to create dynamic array this way could use up lots of memory. Try with this line instead

```
var objectIDArray = [String](count: 40, repeatedValue: "")
```